# Unified MVC and Web Api - same controller for views and json?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

One of the new features in visual studio 2015 (preview) is that "ASP.NET MVC and Web API... have been unified into a single programming model."

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/11/12/announcing-asp-net-features-in-visual-studio-2015-preview-and-vs2013-update-4.aspx

I assumed that this meant that I could write a single controller action "GetCustomerById", that returned a Customer object and that it could be rendered either as serialized Json or as Html (using an mvc view) based on content negotiation. (if the user requested it with "Accept: application/json" or "Accept:  text/html")

But I cannot see how this can be done, they still seem to require different controller and methods?

Comment: As I understood they just merged two libraries into one: http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/aspnet-5-overview#unify

Comment: Yes, and they actually write that "You no longer need to write slightly different code depending on whether you are within an MVC, Web API, or Web Pages context", so I'm assuming that there is a way to write one single action (for both json and html response)? Otherwise I need to duplicate the code

Comment: Yeah, but they don't show it anywhere in their samples, which makes me think that such functionality won't be there

Comment: From looking at the examples (http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6), it looks like it will be heavily attribute based routing. So if you have MVC and WebApi in the same controller, you'd have to apply the attribute routing to each action method instead of at the controller level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done without the new unified model. In any MVC controller you can inspect the headers as well as the `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` method to determine whether how to return data.

Here is bare-bones simplified example of such a method:

```
internal ActionResult ReturnResultAsRequested(object result)
{
  if (Request.Headers["Accept"].Contains("application/json"))
    return Json(result);
  else if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    return PartialView(Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Action"], result);
  else
    return View(Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Action"], result);
}
```

Comment: Hm. In ASP.NET vNext you don't have IsAjaxRequest and RequestContext. You cannot also define route above controller and than use that controller as regular MVC controller.